# wp_localize_script: why is it called localization while it is actually creating a global variable?

Tags: wordpress, localization

I am trying to understand `wp_localize_script` and did the test below:

```
wp_register_script('test',get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/test.js',['jquery']);
wp_localize_script('test','TEST',
    array(
            'wsk' => 'asdn'
    )
);
wp_enqueue_script( 'test');
```

And in test.js I put

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  console.log(TEST);
})
```

When I load the page, it can output the value of `TEST` in the console. What I don't understand is, why is it called "localize"? Because there is actually a global variable TEST created.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/#more-information):

> This function localizes a registered script with data for a JavaScript
> variable.
>
> This lets you offer properly localized translations of any strings
> used in your script. This is necessary because WordPress currently
> only offers a localization API in PHP, not directly in JavaScript (but
> see ticket #20491).
>
> Though localization is the primary use, it was often used to pass
> generic data from PHP to JavaScript, because it was originally the
> only official way to do that. [wp_add_inline_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/) was [introduced in
> WordPress Version 4.5](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/03/08/enhanced-script-loader-in-wordpress-4-5/), and is now the best practice for that use case.
> [wp_localize_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) should only be used when you actually want to
> localize strings.

Basically, the original purpose of the function is to allow developers to translate (or *localize*) text using the localization API so these strings could be used in JavaScript.

For example (taken from the documentation page as well):

```php
// Register the script
wp_register_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );
 
// Localize the script with new data
$translation_array = array(
    'some_string' => __( 'Some string to translate', 'plugin-domain' ),
    'a_value' => '10'
);
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );
 
// Enqueued script with localized data.
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
```

Then on your JS code you could do reference the translated string via the `object_name` object, like this for example:

```js
// alerts 'Some string to translate'
alert( object_name.some_string );
```

People then realized that you could use this function to add anything to the page via inline script, not just translation strings, and so it became a common practice.

Nowadays though, and as the documentation recommends, we should be using `wp_add_inline_script()` instead.

Comment: So the "localize" here is originally meant for translation of spoken languages instead of something like "localize the variable"?

Comment: Exactly @shenkwen